# Does NTFS intentionally leave gaps between files?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

When reading out the distribution of allocated clusters with FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP on a NTFS formatted USB flash drive, I notice that there are large areas of free clusters interspersed. This is even so, when the flash drive has been freshly formatted before the files were copied on it. On a FAT32 drive, by contrast, after formatting and copying, the allocated clusters are contagious.

Is this normal NTFS behaviour, perhaps a strategy to prevent fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it might be wear leveling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) but I do not think NTFS supports this.

Are you sure it is formatted in NTFS and not exFAT?

Comment: Wear leveling is usually implemented in the storage devices itself (unless we're talking about embedded computers). So that's not it. NTFS has no support for wear leveling anyway.

Answer (score 0):

a FAT** file system saves files into clusters by 16 Bytes or 32 bytes explaining the label of FAT16 & FAT32 and basically wasting disk space.

NTFS however is a little more Dynamic than that files can be saved as their own size but again the RAM causes the files to be saved randomly on to DISK therefor to clean up these empty spaces it is best to run DISK DEFRAG a default program on all versions of windows

Unfortunately any system older than windows 2000/ME does not support the conversion of FAT to NTFS.

that is all I know